# How do I turn the controller timeout to "never"?

Tags: steam, controllers

How do I change the controller settings to never timeout or go to sleep? I cannot find the correct option in Steam. I am using a generic controller.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit in what software you are using that you show in the screen? Personally, I use an Xbox controller on my PC and have never seen an interface like that.

Comment: this the steam interface

Comment: @Kyle Rone This is Steam's "Big Picture" mode which is designed similar to consoles (PS3, XBox One?) and works well with a controller.